# Skip Aero Window Animation

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, animation

How can I disable the "opening" animation of a window under Aero programatically?

When opening a new Form it "pops in" (fade in + a slight scaling transformation).
I want to stop this animation and show the window instantly.

I already tried to set the Location property of the Form to somewhere offscreen, then calling Show(), and then moving it at its correct location.
But that doesn't help, the animation will continue.

Maybe there is some hidden property I can set?

I don't want to disable open/close/minimize/maximize animations globally!
I just want to skip the "window-open" animation of my window.

I already played around with single and multiple calls ShowWindow(...) directly after Form.Show(). But no matter what parameters I pass, doesn't abort the opening-animation.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it! After some trying around with ShowWindow, BorderStyles I found my exact solution:

1. Change the initial "FormBorderStyle" property of the form to one of those:

   - None
   - FixedToolWindow
   - SizeableToolWindow
2. Add a eventhandler to the Forms "Shown" event.
3. Inside the eventhandler, change the FormBorderStyle to "Sizeable" (or any other).

Now the trick is that "none" and "*toolwindow" borderstyles will suppress the opening/popup animation for that form. Than, as soon as the form is being displayed the borderstyle is changed, giving it the original functionality (Icon in the Control-Bar, Minimize/Maximize Buttons etc...)

**Edit**: For everyone who might want to try this too, I have to point out that this <del>can</del> will screw with the actual size of the window when done with PInvoke commands.
If you rely on the size of the window being correct, be sure to resize the the window to its intended size after you done this.

Comment: This works as well:

            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Hide();

Answer (score 0):

This is part of windows visual effects and can be adjusted using the [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Method.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in the question I wrote that I only want to disable the animation for MY window - Not systemwide.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the animation is only take place when the form is shown for the first time.

So here is the trick:

```
var form = new Form();
form.Show();
form.Hide();
form.Show();
```

I tested it only in Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style before and after, like this, which will prevent the fade-out animation.

```
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        this.Show();

        // Do whatever

        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        this.Show();
```